# Can Bluetooth beacon be detected while it's in motion?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm curious to know if smartphones can actually detect Bluetooth beacon which is in motion, say while driving. Can car A detects the beacon in car B if they pass each other?

If yes, what is the speed limit and maximum distance?

Comment: Hm.. Why not? What is the difference?

Comment: Hey, for instance, EZPass requires you to slow down at the booth so the reader can read from the tag. This is my concern. I haven't seen applications that do that so far for a beacon. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Doppler Shift can affect the received data, which is different to just dealing with normal reflections, or at least it will raise the noise level to a point where the data is not usable. I can see how high angular velocities from the position of the bluetooth system trying to detect the target bluetooth system can have problems.

Comment: The doppler effect will be there with one side moving as well.

Comment: Yes. Doppler effect. Apparently, EZPass solved that. Can beacon or in general Bluetooth?

Comment: @EugeneSh. of course, however the example given in the comment above by the OP was the EZPass system, which is a static device reading a bluetooth device in a motor vehicle or similar fast moving object. Obviously the device on the moving vehicle would have issues with any data sent to/from the static host..

Comment: That's a question for the bluetooth stack implementation at the lowest levels - how does the bluetooth RF transceiver and circuitry deal with multi-path, reflections, noise, and doppler? These are hard questions!

Comment: @KyranF I don't think there will be a problem with the Doppler effect on the lowest levels (which is the RF level I assume?) The problem might arise with the packet/data transfer timings at higher levels.

Comment: If the RF issues are dealt with appropriately, then yes it can end up being the software stack timing protocols/problems as well @EugeneSh.  This is all me guessing though btw.

Comment: C'mon folks, this is an engineering site.  Before claiming "doppler shift will cause problems", do a [quick calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) of how much doppler will shift the carrier frequency... then compare that to typical inaccuracy of clock crystals and resonators.  (Hint: the relative velocity between the cars is not relativistic motion)

Comment: RF levels will change quite a lot and any AGC circuits may not react fast enough to the variation.  It is not to be expected that Bluetooth was originally designed for the moving application market.

Comment: @KalleMP I have a feeling Bluetooth is not meant for motion application too. At least not yet. I'd say RF is the best bet for now.

Answer (score 1):

Barring [externally designed limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Restrictions_on_civilian_use) or strange relativistic cars, the main concern will be if the vehicles are close enough for long enough to establish a connection and communicate the necessary information.

Suppose car A is moving at speed \$\Delta v\$ relative to car B, your wireless device has an effective range of \$d\$, and the two cars are initially out of communication range. Then the time you have available to connect and communicate is:

\begin{gather}
t = \frac{2 d}{\Delta v}
\end{gather}

Typical passing speed might be ~10mph, and assuming your bluetooth device has the [class 2 radio range of 10m](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Basics.aspx), the time available is [about 4.5 seconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2*10m%2F10mph). If we assume instead that \$\Delta v = 80mph\$, you have ~0.56 seconds. Whether this is enough time depends on your actual devices and the amount of data you need to send.